# RegEx, matching a whole word that has an optional ending

Tags: regex

With the following guide in mind 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Why does this not match words that end with foo or foobar?

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]+foo(?:bar)*\b/i
```

It's supposed to be part of a wordfilter for 4chan.orgs technology board, applied by an addon called 4chanX. I pretty much pasted the code verbatim to filter comments containing the words.

Comment: I think it does. Do you have examples where it doesn't work?

Comment: I think it even matches words ending with `foobarbar`.

Comment: For me it does what it's supposed to and as @Svante said it even matches `foobarbar`: [demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/27JsA17_8rBVM1k4)

Comment: @Erius :  Yeah.. I think it will match both .. Can you give your code , input and output ?

Comment: @SujithPS Hm, well it's supposed to be part of a wordfilter for 4chan.orgs technology board, applied by an addon called 4chanX. I pretty much pasted the code verbatim to filter comments containing the words. Didn't work though. Hmmm.

Comment: Would you mind showing us the code where you execute this regex? Perhaps there's an error in this part rather than the regex itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need of `*`, a `?` will do it for you.

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]+foo(?:bar)?\b/i
```

also if you're trying to find all words of that pattern in your string, you should add `g` modifier if it's available for your regex engine:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]+foo(?:bar)?\b/ig
```

Comment: The first did the trick, a global match is not necessary, only a single one anywhere in the comment. Thanks!